# Receving XML using AS3 AIR URLLoader POST

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to validate a key, receving a xml with the key that the user send to server and the boolean value:

```
public function restServiceCall(event:MouseEvent = null):void 
{
        pswdString = txtKey.text;

        // Create the HTTP request object
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://jpiaget.com.br/webservice.php");
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

        var criptedKey:String = AES.encrypt(pswdString, chave, 256);

        // Add the URL variables
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.versao = "1.1"
        variables.chave = criptedKey;

        request.data = variables;

        // Initiate the transaction
        requestor = new URLLoader();
        requestor.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        requestor.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, httpRequestComplete);
        requestor.load(request);
}

private function httpRequestComplete(event:Event):void 
{
        trace(event.target.data); // This is returning a string with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Result valida="1" nome="xxx" instituicao="xxx"></Result>
        var newString:String = event.target.data;

                    // EDITED!
        var newXML:XML = new XML(event.target.data); 
        trace(newXML); // Here i got nothing
}
```

I already tryed to change the xml version on PHP, change the content-type propriety of URLRequest, change the requestHeaders of URLRequest, and now i'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post the full error you're receiving, my assumption is that the type coercion is that of attempting to assign a `String` to an `XML`.

Change:

`var newXML:XML = event.target.data;`

to:

`var newXML:XML = new XML(event.target.data);`

Comment: Sorry, i tried that too. Actually, the code was like you said, but i changed to see if it change something.

Comment: You're tracing `newXML` and getting nothing because there are no text elements in the XML. If you trace `newXML.toXMLString()` instead, you'll see an actual result.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself, it's a very common mistake. Glad I was able to help.